# How to Add a Payment Method Filter Field to Order Collection

Tags: orders, api, payment, filter

At the moment I have this code:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('state',array(array('like'=>'processing')));
```

Is there a way to add a filter to getCollection() to also filter the orders by payment method or description? something along the lines of:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('state',array(array('like'=>'processing')))
    ->addFieldToFilter('method',array(array('nlike'=>'paypal')));
```

If it is only possible by using the filter on single orders, how would i go about doing that? This doesnt seem to work:

```
$invoices = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($parentOrderNr)
    ->addFieldToFilter('method',array(array('nlike'=>'paypal')));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to append the `sales_flat_order_payment` table to collection:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->join(
        array('payment' => 'sales/order_payment'),
        'main_table.entity_id=payment.parent_id',
        array('payment_method' => 'payment.method')
    );

$collection->addFieldToFilter('payment.method', array(array('nlike' => 'paypal')))
    ->addFieldToFilter('state', array(array('like' => 'processing')));
```

Comment: I had to change a little, but your answer is still a huge help and time saver!

Comment: I think you would not have to use 'like' or 'nlike'. You can also just use `addFieldToFilter('payment.method', array('neq' => 'paypal'))` instead of 'nlike' and just use `->addFieldToFilter('state', 'processing')` instead of 'like'.